# Verificar campos de formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe alguma função ou método que verifica se todos os campos de um formulário estão preenchido?

Ex: `$("#formElement").fieldsFilled()`

Aceito respostas tanto em javascript puro quanto em jquery.

Comment: Deixe o título mais descritivo pois esse é difícil de encontrar com engines de busca. Sugestão: *Método para verifica se todos os campos de um formulário estão preenchido?*

Answer (score 2):

Sim, você pode obter todos os campos de um formulário usando **`HTMLFormElement.elements`** e iterar com um `for` ou `for..of`, segue o exemplo (clique para exibir o código):

```js
function checkEmptyFields() {
  const inputs = document.getElementById("formulario1").elements;

  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    const input = inputs[i];
    
    if (input.value === '') { // Aqui na IF fica a sua lógica
       console.error('Campo não preenchido');
       return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario1">
<input type="text" value="foobar" id="campo1">
<input type="text" value="" id="campo2">
<input type="text" value="" id="campo3">
</form>

<button onclick="console.log(checkEmptyFields());">Checar</button>
```

Para checar cada campo no `for` (ou até unitário) preenchido, ou não, você pode usar duas propriedades, se a intenção é verificar se o campo está apenas preenchido basta verificar se `HTMLInputElement.value` é vazio, isso servirá para a maioria dos dos campos.

No caso do tipo `type=file` você pode checar se a propriedade `HTMLInputElement.files` possui itens, principalmente no caso de selecionar multiplos arquivos, você poderá checar a quantidade de itens com `HTMLInputElement.files.length`.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
function checkEmptyFields() {
  const campo1 = document.getElementById('campo1');
  const campo2 = document.getElementById('campo2');
  const campo3 = document.getElementById('campo3');

  console.log('campo1 está preenchido:', campo1.value !== '');
  console.log('campo2 está preenchido:', campo2.value !== '');
  console.log('campo3 tem um arquivo selecionado:', campo3.files.length !== 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="foobar" id="campo1"><br>
<input type="text" value="" id="campo2"><br>
<input type="file" value="foobar" id="campo3"><br>

<button onclick="checkEmptyFields()">Checar</button>
```

Então uma simples `if` poderá confirmar, exemplos:

```js
// Checar a maioria
if (campo.value !== '') {
    console.log('Campo preenchido');
} else {
    console.log('Campo vazio');
}

if (campo.files.length) {
    console.log('Arquivo selecionado');
} else {
    console.log('Não foi selecionado um arquivo');
}
```

---

### Checando se o usuário alterou o valor com `defaultValue`

Se deseja verificar se os campos foram alterados você pode usar a propriedade `HTMLInputElement.defaultValue` e compara-la com `HTMLInputElement.value`, exemplo:

```js
function checkEmptyFields() {
  const campo1 = document.getElementById('campo1');

  if (campo1.defaultValue !== campo1.value) {
    console.info('O campo foi alterado pelo usuário');
  } else {
    console.error('O campo está com o valor padrão, o usuário não alterou');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="foobar" id="campo1">
<button onclick="checkEmptyFields()">Checar</button>
```

---

### Validando campos com required e reportValidity()

O caminho ideal atualmente é usar o atributo `required` combinado com o método `HTMLFormElement.reportValidity()` (acaso precise de uma validação customizada), para checar se os campos necessários foram preenchidos, pois podem haver campos opcionais, ou até validar os valores diretamente com atributo HTML `pattern="<regex>"`

Exemplo de uso:

```js
function checkValidForm() {
  const form = document.getElementById("formulario1");

  if (form.reportValidity()) {
    console.info('Formulário valido');
  } else {
    console.error('Formulário invalido');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario1">
<input type="text" value="" name="campo1" required placeholder="Nome">
<input type="email" value="outro" name="campo2" required placeholder="E-mail">
<input type="number" value="2" min="3" name="campo3" required placeholder="Entradas (min 3)">
<input type="text" pattern="\d{4,4}" value="55555" required placeholder="PIN">
</form>

<button onclick="checkValidForm()">Checar</button>
```